# Bootstrap collapse class doesn't toggle correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the Bootstrap collapse class. I have two issues. The first is when I click my collapse button initially, it takes a second click to collapse the div. Second, when it does collapse the text contained with the div is still visible. I can tell collapse is doing something because I added a border around the outer div.

JSFiddle demonstrating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/sw52dytm/3/

```html
<div style="border: 3px solid #A9A9A9">
  <button data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#Info_Collapse"
          class="btn btn-link collapsed">collapse</button>
  <h2>Info</h2>
  <div class="accordion-body collapse show" id="Info_Collapse">
    <span>test</span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet. I have changed some classes

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="border: 3px solid #A9A9A9">
  <h2>Info</h2>
  <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    collapse
  </button>

  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">

    <span>test</span>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**EDITED:**

*Loading with expanding the content*

Changed log: `aria-expanded="true"` and adding show class to

```
<div class="collapse show" id="collapseExample">
```

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="border: 3px solid #A9A9A9">
  <h2>Info</h2>
  <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        collapse
      </button>

  <div class="collapse show" id="collapseExample">

    <span>test</span>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

For more information you can refer bootstrap 4 documentation. The relevant link is provided below.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Comment: Thanks this is just what I was looking for except for one detail. I it to load expanded. What needs to change to have that happen?

Comment: Perfect. So you want it to load expanded first and then when you click collapse button, it should hide? Basically other way around right

Comment: @yes, that is exactly it. sorry if that was not clear from the question.

Comment: no problem, i edited the answer again with the changes. Check now

Comment: Thanks. I see it works great in your example, but in my fiddle, I have the same problem I was having originally when I use your code. See updated: https://jsfiddle.net/sw52dytm/8/ Any thoughts on what the difference is?

Comment: Remove all your external scripts and use the scripts in the answer and see? Maybe some other external library might days the issue

Comment: You were right. You're solution seems to work with Bootstrap 4.0  beta. I am using 3.3.5. It's part of a larger project and I'm afraid to upgrade without needing to address a lot of other issues. Any idea how to make this work in 3.3.5? http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: https://www.quackit.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_3/tutorial/bootstrap_collapse.cfm

Check this out

Comment: I was confusing when every collapsable trigger both collapse and expand on the first time click, although after that everything work normally.
I was missing "show" class in the collapsable div. I'm glad that i read your answer