# Bootstrap, first data-toggle click doesn't work or data are not displayed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I tried to set `<div id="rowAngleOutputDiv0">` expanded initialy.
The identical issue was described here 
[Bootstrap data-toggle collapses div after second click, not first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290431/bootstrap-data-toggle-collapses-div-after-second-click-not-first) .
I have added `class="collapse in"` as it was described. But in my case that solution doesn't work. If I add `class="collapse in"` , div element initialy will be hidden.

1. How to set `<div id="rowAngleOutputDiv0">` initialy expanded and avoid 'bootstrap data-toggle first click doesn't work' issue?
2. If I leave `class="collapse in"` then all children are hidden even if I click button to show them. How to make those children visible after button click, if `class="collapse (in)"` is set?

   ```
   <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#rowAngleOutputDiv0"></button>
   <div id="rowAngleOutputDiv0" class="collapse in">

       <div class="row">
           <div id="angleOutputDiv0">
               <canvas id="angleOutput0"></canvas>
           </div>
           <div>
               <div id="dygraphOutC0"></div>
               <div id="dygraphOutC1"></div>
               <div id="dygraphOutC2"></div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap collapse class doesn't toggle correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325783/bootstrap-collapse-class-doesnt-toggle-correctly)

Comment: @Ryankozak It is not duplicated. As I wrote in my answer, before you commented, solution from the link didn't work in my case - I can't explain why. But I replaced 'in' with 'show' and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `class="collapse in"` with `class="collapse show"`.

That question
[Bootstrap collapse class doesn't toggle correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325783/bootstrap-collapse-class-doesnt-toggle-correctly?rq=1)
 direct me slightly to the solution